# Fallback intent as a search

Tags: dialogflow-es

The bot which I have created within **Dialogflow** is using a webhook to link to our external site.

- One of the intents we have for the bot is to search for knowledge
  within the site. Originally, we had in the Request Knowledge intent,
  a phrase which was a @sys.any parameter, which would then be the
  search term.
- However, because the whole phrase was a @sys.any parameter, this
  would be prioritised over most other intents.
- We are trying to get users to use natural language when using the
  bot, however people still do just type in one word or a phrase for
  the search function.
- What I would like if possible is to have a fallback intent which is
  the search function. So if the bot cannot successfully match the one
  word, it would then run a search for this word.

  I am not sure if this would fix this problem or just produce more issues.

  If anyone has solved something similar to this, I would greatly appreciate the help. Sorry if this is simple to do, I am all new to the whole Dialogflow world!

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn fulfillment on for Fallback Intents, and these will be sent to your webhook. The JSON includes the full text of what was entered.

However... the results will clearly be less useful since some of the results will be text that is conversational, but didn't get picked up by one of the other Intents.